# Why does calling sumr on a stream with 50 tuples not complete

Tags: scala, stream, scalaz

While investigating a bug today, I noticed that calling `sumr` on a stream with 50 `(Int, Int)` tuples never completes, but it does on a smaller stream. Calling `.toList` on the larger stream first completes as well.

Is this the intended behavior when calling `sumr` on a large stream? Does it not evaluate the stream to completion, or is something else causing this?

```
scala> val strSmall = Stream((1,1),(2,4),(3,9),(4,16),(5,25))
strSmall: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[(Int, Int)] = Stream((1,1), ?)

scala> val strBig = Stream((1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0))
strBig: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[(Int, Int)] = Stream((1,0), ?)

scala> strSmall.sumr
res3: (Int, Int) = (15,55)

scala> strBig.toList.sumr
res4: (Int, Int) = (47,3)

scala> strBig.sumr
<!-- never completes -->
```

Answer (score 2):

`sumr` is implemented in terms of `foldRight`:

```
 final def sumr(implicit A: Monoid[A]): A = F.foldRight(self, A.zero)(A.append)
```

`foldRight` is not always tail recursive, so you can overflow the stack if the collection is too long. See [Why foldRight and reduceRight are NOT tail recursive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085118/why-foldright-and-reduceright-are-not-tail-recursive) for some more discussion of when this is or isn't true.

Comment: I did initially suspect something like that might be going on, and even wrapped the call in a try/catch hoping to catch a stack overflow exception, but no exception was thrown. It seems to just continue without completing.

Comment: 50 items does seem a very small size to fail from recursion. Have you tried replacing the sumr with the foldRight directly to start pealing away layers? Also, do you see any problem with suml?