# Converting List[JsObject] to JsArray with Fold

Tags: scala, recursion, playframework

Can a `fold` be used here to convert from a `List[JsObject]` to `JsArray`?

```
    def getJsonArray(list: List[JsObject]): JsArray = {
        def go(l: List[JsObject], acc: JsArray) : JsArray = l match {
            case x :: xs => go(xs, acc ++ Json.arr(x))
            case Nil => acc
        }
        go(list, JsArray())
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this should be roughly equivalent:

```
  def getJsonArray(list: List[JsObject]): JsArray = {
    list.foldLeft(JsArray())((acc, x) => acc ++ Json.arr(x))
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Why did you pick foldLeft over foldRight?

Comment: `foldRight` starts at the head of the list and builds up a giant function going to the end, and then applies that function which can lead to a stack overflow. `foldLeft` starts at the head of the list and applies your function, then goes to the next element so you don't have a giant built up function which can cause a stack overflow. For a better answer you can look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446419/how-do-you-know-when-to-use-fold-left-and-when-to-use-fold-right

Comment: Why don't use ```(acc, x) => acc +: x```?

Comment: I think you mean `acc :+ x` and I just copied the supplied function from the question

Comment: using fold like that keeps accumulating results into JsArray which is immutable, meaning a new JsArray object is constructed for every element in the list. Is there not a better way to do this?

Comment: @Khorkhe, no, if you allow for mutability, get rid of the `foldLeft`, then yeah sure you can probably come up with a more memory efficient way.