# Common lisp: How to implement reduce

Tags: list, functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp, reduce

I've been looking for this for days, basically I need to implement a function that does the same thing that the system function reduce does. This is what I have came up so far, but without an initial value `i` I can't get it to work.

Here is my code

```
(defun my-reduce (p i lista)
  (if (null lista)
       i
    (funcall p (car lista) (my-reduce p i (cdr lista)))))
```

By the way, it doesn't even work properly because it goes "backward"
eg.:

```
(my-reduce #'list NIL '(1 2 3 4))
```

should return

> (((1 2) 3) 4)

but I get

> (1 (2 (3 (4 NIL))))

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have implemented a correct right fold, as this is usually called, but want a left fold. Note the characteristic tail recursion, and using the "default" value as accumulator:

```
(defun my-left-reduce (f i xs)
  (if (null xs)
       i
    (my-left-reduce f (funcall f i (car xs)) (cdr xs))
```

(And I've never used Common Lisp, but the concept should be clear.)

---

Aside: usually it's the left fold that is considered "backwards". Compare `(my-reduce cons NIL '(1 2 3))` and `(my-left-reduce cons NIL '(1 2 3))`. The latter should invert the original cons structure of the list.

Comment: Thank you so much!! is there a way that you know to don't display the `NIL` in the output?

Comment: @user7337963 The standard function takes a keyword argument `:initial-value` if not set it would be as if you had called it with the `cdr` of the list and used the `car` as initial value. When the keyword argument `:from-end` is set to true it does the elements like a right fold.

Comment: @Sylwester thank you, I combined what you told me with phg's solution and i made a function with 2 arguments that call's my-reduce !

Comment: @user7337963 That will work. You could also have defined the helper inside with [`labels`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_flet_.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Left fold can be implemented with a simple iteration:

```
(defun my-fold-left (reducer initial list)
  (loop for fold = initial then (funcall reducer fold element)
        for element in list
        finally (return fold)))
```

For example:

```
(my-fold-left #'cons 0 '(1 2 3 4))
((((0 . 1) . 2) . 3) . 4)

(my-fold-left #'cons 0 '())
0
```

You can generalize and fold over vectors too if you use `map`:

```
(defun my-fold-left (reducer fold sequence)
  (map nil
       (lambda (e) (setf fold (funcall reducer fold e)))
       sequence)
  fold)
```

Just in case you did not read it, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1446478/124319) has a nice high-level explanation of left and right fold.

Comment: Thank's! unfortunately i'm no allowed to use setf

Comment: You are allowed, outside of the class ;-)

Comment: Oh yes that's fore sure :) but unfortunately for all my class assignment i'm not allowed to use loops, set setf or setq... anyway i will keep in mind your answer