# Convert a string representing a binary number to a base 10 string haskell

Tags: haskell

I have the string "1001" and I want the string "9".

The numeric library has the (rather clunky) showIntAtBase, but I haven't been able to find the opposite.

Comment: None of these functions convert to decimal.  They convert from a string representing a number in base 2 to the machine's native integer format, which, unless you are using some exotic hardware, is most assuredly a packed binary representation.  It is the show function that, when applied to the integer, generates a string representing the number in base 10.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is more or less what you were looking for from Prelude.
From [Numeric](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/numeric.html):

> (NB: readInt is the "dual" of showIntAtBase, and readDec is the "dual" of showInt. The inconsistent naming is a historical accident.)

```
import Data.Char  (digitToInt)
import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)
import Numeric    (readInt)

readBin :: Integral a => String -> Maybe a
readBin = fmap fst . listToMaybe . readInt 2 (`elem` "01") digitToInt
-- readBin "1001" == Just 9
```

Comment: One can also use `digitToInt = subtract (fromEnum '0') . fromEnum` instead, which works for all decimal digits (the built-in implementation of `digitToInt` handles hexadecimal digits as well).

Answer (score 23):

It's been a while since the original post but, for future readers' benefit, I would use the following:

```
import Data.Char (digitToInt)
import Data.List (foldl')

toDec :: String -> Int
toDec = foldl' (\acc x -> acc * 2 + digitToInt x) 0
```

No need to slow things down by using `^`, `reverse`, `zipWith`, `length`, etc.

Also, using a strict fold reduces memory requirements.

Answer (score 3):

From [PLEAC](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_haskell/numbers.html#AEN82):

```
bin2dec :: String -> Integer
bin2dec = foldr (\c s -> s * 2 + c) 0 . reverse . map c2i
    where c2i c = if c == '0' then 0 else 1
```

Comment: Using a right fold forces you to reverse the intermediate list. Why not use a *left* fold, here, instead?

Answer (score 2):

This helps? http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_haskell/numbers.html

from the page:

```
bin2dec :: String -> Integer
bin2dec = foldr (\c s -> s * 2 + c) 0 . reverse . map c2i
    where c2i c = if c == '0' then 0 else 1
-- bin2dec "0110110" == 54
```

Comment: Why do they reverse and then foldr instead of foldl?

Comment: @mathepic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384797/implications-of-foldr-vs-foldl-or-foldl

Comment: @shintoist I understand the difference. I should have said `foldl'`

Comment: @shintoist: Unless I'm missing something, nothing in that link suggests that `foldr` and `reverse` are preferable to `foldl'` here. As a matter of fact, I can only see downsides to using `foldr` and `reverse` here.

Comment: @sepp2k no, I agree, I don't see a reason either to using foldr and reverse over foldl', but I understood the question as foldr vs regular foldl.

Comment: I'm +1ing this despite the fact that I normally don't +1 sloppy code (ie reverse then foldr) that is copied but not looked over, only because there is another answer, exactly the same, that had one more upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Because

```
1001 = 1 * 2^0 + 0 * 2^1 + 0 * 2^2 + 1 * 2^3 = 1 + 0 + 0 + 8 = 9

┌───┬───┬───┬───┐
│1  │0  │0  │1  │
├───┼───┼───┼───┤
│2^3│2^2│2^1│2^0│
└───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

so obviously:

```
fromBinary :: String -> Int
fromBinary str = sum $ zipWith toDec (reverse str) [0 .. length str]
  where toDec a b = digitToInt a * (2 ^ b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
binario :: Int -> [Int]                      
binario 1 = [1]                  
binario n = binario(div x 2)++(mod n 2:[])
```

credits to @laionzera

Answer (score 0):

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Bits (shift)

-- Dirty version

binToInt :: String -> Int
binToInt = foldl' step 0
  where
    step acc '1' = shift acc 1 + 1
    step acc _   = shift acc 1

-- Maybe version

mayBinToInt :: String -> Maybe Int
mayBinToInt = foldM step 0
  where
    step acc '0' = pure $ shift acc 1
    step acc '1' = pure $ shift acc 1 + 1
    step acc _   = Nothing
```

(Of course you might want to return `Nothing` on empty string in the second one as well.)