# Data.Bits operation on binary represention

Tags: haskell, bitwise-operators

I want to use Data.Bits bitwise operators on a binary data.
What data type I need to use? 
I wrote this function for example :

```
ch :: Int8 -> Int8 -> Int8 -> Int8
ch x y z = (x .&. y) `xor` ((complement x) .|. z)
```

I want to get as input binary type or at least `String` (not `Int`) but still use Data.Bits

So what I need to change to use it like this for example? :
`ch 11111111 101110011 10110101`

Comment: Binary data? Like a stream of `Word8`? A `ByteString`?

Comment: Well im not sure. Im tring to implement "sha256" function so Im getting `String` of text as input and immediately conveting it to the representing binary text. so now it is `String`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written, `ch` will only take `Int8` values, but you can relax the type of the function without changing its implementation:

```
import Data.Bits

ch :: Bits a => a -> a -> a -> a
ch x y z = (x .&. y) `xor` (complement x .|. z)
```

Binary values are just particular representations of integers, but to make things more readable, you can enable `BinaryLiterals`, e.g. like this in GHCi:

```
*Q48065001> :set -XBinaryLiterals
*Q48065001> ch 0b11111111 0b101110011 0b10110101
-58
```

In a code file, you can enable that with a language pragma:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BinaryLiterals #-}
```

---

If you have string representation of binary numbers, you'll first need to parse those. See e.g. [Convert a string representing a binary number to a base 10 string haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5921573/126014)

Comment: Thank you. one small thing, giving string `"11111111"` representation how do you convert to `0b11111111` `BinaryLiterals` type?

Comment: But he is converting to the representing integer. I think I missed how to change it to convert to the `0bXXX` type we talked about.

Comment: @limitless An expression like `0b101010` isn't a data type; it's a representation. It's just a way to write the number `42`. If you go `0b101010 :: Int8` it's `42` as an `Int8`. If you go `0b101010 :: Word64`, it's `42` as a `Word64`. You can also represent `42` a hexadecimal number, like this: `0x2a :: Word64`. It's still `42` as a `Word64`; it's just two different ways of writing it.

Answer (score 0):

A good choice for I/O on binary data is [`Data.ByteString.Lazy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.1/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html), a highly-optimized library for reading `Word8` values.  It includes analogues for most of the list and I/O functions in the `Prelude` and in `Data.List`, and is well-suited for efficient interactive I/O because it reads bytes in and can write them out as a lazily-evaluated list of strict arrays.  It also has efficient functions to convert to and from various encodings.  See also [this tutorial](https://wiki.haskell.org/Dealing_with_binary_data).