# How to convert String to BinaryLiterals

Tags: haskell

Is there anyway to convert `String` to `BinaryLiterals` type?

For example `"11001100"` to `0b11001100`

Comment: BinaryLiterals is not a type but an extension that lets you type in numbers in binary which then are interpreted as any other number (i.e. `fromInteger`).  If you simply want to parse binary then you could map `digitToInt` and `zipWith (*) powersOfTwo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `readBin` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5922212/126014, you can parse a binary string representation of a number into an `Maybe Integral` of your choice, e.g.:

```
*Q48065932> readBin "11001100"
Just 204
```

`11001100` is just the binary representation of the (decimal) integer `204`. Using `BinaryLiterals`, you can write that number using binary representation:

```
*Q48065932> :set -XBinaryLiterals
*Q48065932> Just 0b11001100
Just 204
```

If you want the integer to be a particular type (say: `Word8`), you can do that for both expressions:

```
*Q48065932 Data.Word> readBin "11001100" :: Maybe Word8
Just 204
*Q48065932 Data.Word> Just 0b11001100 :: Maybe Word8
Just 204
```

You can convince yourself that these two expressions have the same value by comparing them:

```
*Q48065932 Data.Word> readBin "11001100" == Just 0b11001100
True
```

You can also write the number `204` using hexadecimal notation, like this:

```
*Q48065932 Data.Word> Just 0xCC
Just 204
```

That's still equal to `11001100`:

```
*Q48065932 Data.Word> Just 0xCC == readBin "11001100"
True
*Q48065932 Data.Word> Just 0xCC == Just 204
True
```

All of these expressions are equal to each other because they're the same number (`204`); they're just different ways to write the same number. The data type used to store that number in memory (`Int`, `Word8`, etc.) is independent of how you write the literal numbers.