# GHCI not so lazy on Windows?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, ghci

Typing following into GHCI on Windows:

```
foldl (+) 0 $ take 100000000 $ map sqrt [1..]
```

gives:

```
<interactive>: out of memory
```

while compiling (with GHC) and running this program:

```
main = do
    let score = foldl (+) 0 $ take 100000000 $ map sqrt [1..]
    putStrLn $ show score
```

prints expected answer without memory error.

Is there a reason for this behavior ? It seems to me like laziness of Haskell should prevent this one liner from crashing.

Comment: The problem is actually too much laziness.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's just GHC doing strictness and other optimizations. GHCi doesn't do the same sort of optimizations that the full compiler does.

In particular that `foldl` is building up way too many thunks and those are causing your overflow. However when I change this to the strict `foldl'` even GHCi can handle it. You should read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384797/implications-of-foldr-vs-foldl-or-foldl) to learn a bit more about why this is.