# Higher order function specifics with foldr and foldl

Tags: haskell, fold, combinators

I'm having trouble interpreting the function signature for foldl. I understand how it works, but I'm not sure how it relates to the signature.

I have a few questions about its detail

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b

foldr (+) 5 [1,2,3,4]
```

It seems like the first parameter takes an addition function:

```
(a -> b -> b)
```

Within the function argument, what exactly is happening? Does this section apply the right-most integer `a` to the accumulator `b` to yield another integer 9 in this case? After this, does it then return a function that takes the accumulator as a parameter?

And following this, what do the last two parameters below mean?

```
[a] -> b
```

Many thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implications of foldr vs. foldl (or foldl')](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384797/implications-of-foldr-vs-foldl-or-foldl)

Answer (score 5):

When you pass `(+)` in to the first argument of `foldr` you implicitly declare that `a` is the same as `b`. This gets confusing since we tend to reuse names, but if I write it all together using the same namespace for the type variables

```
(+)       :: Num i => i -> i -> i
foldr     :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr (+) :: Num i => i -> [i] -> i
```

where the third line implies that `i ~ a` and `i ~ b` thus, by transitivity, `a ~ b`. Also, it might be more clear here to see that the first remaining parameter in `foldr (+)` is an "initial" value for the fold and the `[i]` bit is the list that we're compressing, folding, reducing.

It might be even more clear to call `foldr (+) 0` by it's more common name, `sum :: Num a => [a] -> a`. We also have `foldr (*) 1` as `product :: Num a => a -> [a]`.

So yes, your description of how the accumulator function is behaving in `foldr (+)` is exactly correct, but more specific than the function is in general. For instance, we can use `foldr` to build a `Map`.

```
foldr (\(k, v) m -> Map.insert m k v) Map.empty :: Ord k => [(k, v)] -> Map k v
```

In this case the accumulator function takes our association list and keeps inserting the values into our accumulat*ing* `Map`, which begins empty. To be utterly thorough here, let me write out the types all together again

```
(\(k, v) -> m -> Map.insert m k v)       :: Ord k => (k, v) -> Map k v -> Map k v
foldr                                    :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr (\(k, v) -> m -> Map.insert m k v) :: Ord k => Map k v -> [(k, v)] -> Map k v
```

where we've forced `a ~ (k, v)` and `b ~ Map k v`.

---

As a final view on the matter, here's the definition of foldr with some suggestive variable names

```
foldr _    b []     = b
foldr (<>) b (a:as) = a <> foldr f b as
```

So you can see how `(<>) :: a -> b -> b` combines `a` and `b` types. We can "run" this definition explicitly to see how it builds up the computation.

```
foldr (+) 0 [1,2,3]
1 + (foldr (+) 0 [2,3])
1 + (2 + (foldr (+) 0 [3]))
1 + (2 + (3 + (foldr (+) 0 [])))
1 + (2 + (3 + 0))
1 + (2 + 3)
1 + 5
6
```

Which may be even more clear when we use a non-symmetric operation like the `Map` example above. Below I'm using `{{ k -> v, k -> v }}` to represent the `Map` since it isn't printable directly.

```
-- inserts a single (k,v) pair into a Map
ins :: Ord k => (k, v) -> Map k v -> Map k v
ins (k, v) m = Map.insert m k v

foldr ins Map.empty [('a', 1), ('b', 2)]
ins ('a', 1) (foldr ins Map.empty [('b', 2)])
ins ('a', 1) (ins ('b', 2) (foldr ins Map.empty []))
ins ('a', 1) (ins ('b', 2) Map.empty)
ins ('a', 1) (ins ('b', 2) {{  }})
ins ('a', 1) {{ 'b' -> 2 }}
{{ 'b' -> 2, 'a' -> 1 }}
```

Comment: I think `sum` and `product` are defined through `foldl'`

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Unfortunately I'm still a bit confused, and I'm attempting to take a step back and look at the whole picture first. So the first parameter is a function `(+)` that takes the current value of a list element `[a]` and the accumulator `b` to give the new accumulator value `b` The second argument is the accumulator `b` which also takes the third argument, a list element `[a]` and returns the new accumulator value `b` (which is a result of applying the function to the second and third argument)? And do we apply this function until we are left with an accumulator...

Comment: ...and a list element, which represents `b -> [a] -> b` where the final `b` is our resulting accumulated value? I'm getting this from the operator notation of foldr, where it recursively evaluates the accumulated result. Many thanks again

Comment: @SassaNF They're actually defined with `foldl` and, in GHC, via explicit recursion. Semantically it's all a drop in the bucket until you get a good grasp on what folding is, though.

Comment: @user1272525 I added some explicit reductions which may help to show how the folding function is applied to arguments of types `a` and `b` more clearly. They're a bit long, but if you follow them through you can see the mechanics exactly.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you look at it. The first step yields `(+) 1 (foldr (+) 5 [2,3,4])`. As you try to use the result of folding, this will force the evaluation of the second argument of (+), and since (+) is strict, this unravels the entire list. The last step yields `(+) 1 ((+) 2 ((+) 3 ((+) 4 5)))`. So, yes, the first two numbers added are 4 and 5, yet this is not the first thing foldr does, and in this case you will have the list replaced with a tree of thunks first, then evaluate it to get the sum of all numbers and 5.

The replacing of list with thunks is good in cases where the function is not strict - this way you can evaluate only as much as necessary, even a possibly infinite list. In cases when the function is strict, it makes sense to consider rewriting with `foldl'`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the type signature of foldr:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

It takes a function (call it **step**) that takes the next value (an **a**) and the accumulated value (a **b**) and produces a new accumulated value (also a **b**)

```
step :: a -> b -> b
```

And an inititial accumulator value (a **b**):

```
initialValue :: b
```

And a list of inputs to fold over (a list of **a**'s):

```
inputs :: [a]
```

And finally you get an output (a **b**)

```
output :: b
```

So you get a general form:

```
output = foldr step initialValue inputs
```