# Get first item matching a criteria using foldr

Tags: haskell, fold

I am giving my self exercises and wondering if there is a way to find the first item from left in the list matching a certain criteria using just `foldr`? I want the recursion to stop when the first item is found (I know I could probably combine using `take`) but I am curious to know if it is possible to do just using `foldr`?

```
firstFind (\x -> x > 1000) [] xs
```

Comment: first item from the beginning or the end of the list?

Comment: from left if possible

Comment: *hint*: implement `filter` using a fold and then just use `head` (or a variant that does not bottom out on empty lists if it's important for you)

Comment: mind that finding the first item from the left while examining the list from the right will traverse the whole list anyway.

Comment: @soulcheck I don't think that's right. If we assume we've found the first element `x'` matching `p` in `xs`, and we find that `x` matches `p`, we do not need to inspect `x'` (hence need not compute `x'`) to find the first element matching `p` in `x:xs`.

Comment: @DanielWagner you don't know which one is first if you start from the right. Imagine a simple case where you want to find the first (from the left) odd number in a list, starting from the right. No way to know if there's no more odd numbers to the left of what you found so far unless you actually test them.

Comment: @soulcheck That would be a problem if you were implementing this using `foldl`. `foldr` doesn't start from the right, it associates to the right: http://stackoverflow.com/a/384919/2476735.

Comment: @DavidYoung Ahh, right. It can skip evaluating the right argument if the predicate is true.I always forget how lazy haskell is.

Comment: Surprised nobody's mentioned the `First` monoid.  Combine that with the default definition of `foldMap` to get a working implementation.

Comment: @JohnL It's a bit voodoo, but yes, throw in Control.Newtype and you have `ala' First foldMap :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> Maybe b`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem: find `f` and `b`.

```
firstFind :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe a
firstFind p list = foldr f b list
   where f = ???
         b = ???
```

We want:

```
firstFind p [] = Nothing
```

but we also have

```
firstFind p [] 
= def. firstFind
foldr f b []
= def. foldr
b
```

from which we see what `b` must be.

Further, take `list = x:xs`

```
firstFind p list
= def. firstFind
foldr f b (x:xs)
= def. foldr
f x (foldr f b xs)
= def. firstFind
f x (firstFind p xs)
```

Now, we just need to find `f` so that this chooses the first match.

Recall that `f` can depend on `p`. What should `f` return when `p x` is true? What in the opposite case?

```
where -- f :: a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
      f x y = ???
```

(Note: above I wrote the type signature for `f` for clarity, but you don't have to include it in your code. If you add it, uncommented, you will trip into a type variable confusion: that `a` is not the same `a` as in `findFirst` because it is generalized locally -- since you are just beginning, ignore this and simply remove it for the moment being.)

Comment: Just a minor note: the monomorphism restriction doesn't apply if you give an explicit type signature, so adding it should be fine.

Comment: @bennofs I do not know why I wrote that. Corrected.