# Erlang sublist function performance

Tags: erlang

I'm reading http://learnyousomeerlang.com/ which includes a tail recursive sublist function that reverses the list to preserve order.  I have written an alternative that does not require the reverse call.  Is mine more efficient (it is certainly more verbose, but I'm not concerned with that), or have I overlooked something?

```
-module(sublist).

-export([sublist/2,sublistR/2]).

-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").

sublist(_,0) ->
    [];
sublist([],_) ->
    [];
sublist(List,Length) ->
    sublist([hd(List)], tl(List), Length-1).

sublist(Acc,[],_) ->
    Acc;
sublist(Acc,_,0) ->
    Acc;
sublist(Acc,Tail,Length) ->
    sublist(Acc++[hd(Tail)], tl(Tail), Length-1).

sublistR(L, N) -> lists:reverse(sublistR(L, N, [])).

sublistR(_, 0, SubList) -> SubList;
sublistR([], _, SubList) -> SubList;
sublistR([H|T], N, SubList) when N > 0 ->
    sublistR(T, N-1, [H|SubList]).

sublist_test() ->
    sublisttest(fun sublist:sublist/2),
    sublisttest(fun sublist:sublistR/2).

sublisttest(SublistFunc) ->
    [] = SublistFunc([],10),
    [] = SublistFunc([1,2,3], 0),
    [1,2,3] = SublistFunc([1,2,3],3),
    [1,2,3] = SublistFunc([1,2,3],4),
    [1,2] = SublistFunc([1,2,3],2).
```

Comment: tl;dr: No. But don't lose heart -- you are asking exactly the right sort of questions and doing exactly the right sort of experimentation in code to actually get something out of your self-study. This is a great thing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. But don't feel bad, this is a common thing everyone has to come to terms with early on.

Its all about this statement:

```
Acc ++ [hd(Tail)]
```

Let's say `Acc = [1,2,3]` is true. Then `Acc ++ [hd(Tail)]` is directly equivalent to `[1,2,3 | [Head]]`. What does this mean?

In this particular case it means it is *exactly* the same as writing out *every element* in `Acc` as the car and using the result of `[hd(Tail)]` as the cdr in a new cons. This means to join a single element to the end of an existing list, the entire list must be traversed (for deconstruction, to expose the final cdr). On the other hand, adding a single element to the *beginning* of a list is a simple operation.

The magic in the use of `lists:reverse/1` (and the entire reason this is idiomatic in languages that use cons style lists) is that it is an array operation implemented in C, not an expansion in the object language you're writing right then.

This issue of access to the last element being expensive VS access to the first element is the reason `hd/1` (or `head()` in other languages) returns the first element of a list, but `tl/1` (or `tail()` in other languages) returns everything but the first element of a list. Uses of a function guaranteed to access the last element of a list are usually surrounded by warnings that "this is slow!".

This is also why you will *very rarely* see anyone use a `foldr` in almost any language. If they *really* need to fold from the right (say, because of a non-commutative operation) they will usually do `lists:reverse/1` first, then call `foldl`. `foldl` can be tail-recursive, but a true `foldr` cannot.

Actually, the Erlang documentation has a mention of this: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#foldl-3

The cost of folding from the right increases as the length of the list increases. That is why this happens:

```
1> AMillionThings = lists:seq(1, 1000000).
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,
 23,24,25,26,27,28,29|...]
2> OneThing = [0].
[0]
3> timer:tc(fun() -> OneThing ++ AMillionThings end).
{13,
 [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,
  23,24,25,26|...]}
4> timer:tc(fun() -> AMillionThings ++ OneThing end).
{31291,
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,
  23,24,25,26,27|...]}
```

13μs vs 31291μs. Ouch.

Also see:

- [Implications of foldr vs. foldl (or foldl')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384797/implications-of-foldr-vs-foldl-or-foldl)
- http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/1395
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAR_and_CDR
- http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html

Comment: PS. timer:tc module returns the elapsed time in micro-seconds (us) not milliseconds (ms), http://erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html#tc-1

Comment: @Shawn Indeed, I used the wrong unit of time symbol! I've corrected it now. Thanks for the heads up. :-)