# Erlang: head | tail from the end

Tags: list, erlang

I am just starting Erlang (though with some lisp background) and have a question about pattern matching on lists.

If I say

```
[Head | Tail] = [1, 2, 3].
```

then I get

```
Head = 1
Tail = [2, 3]
```

If I want to do the same from the other end **without reversing the list twice**, is there some succint patter for that? I would like to be able to say something like:

```
[All_but | last] = [1, 2, 3].
```

and get:

```
All_but = [1, 2]
last = 3
```

Thanks.

PS: I know my example is incorrect behavior.

Comment: It might be enlightening to ask yourself why the answer is "no" in lisp (not that Erlang and quite a few lisp implementations don't have some shortcuts built in). What does a chain of conses look like? Why does everyone avoid foldr? etc.

Comment: I understand and agree. Very good point. From a purely recursive point of view however, recursing from the tail or the head are both desirable. So, was just being wishful, I guess.

Comment: "Purely recursive", sure, but not "tail recursive", which is really the point in a functional language and the place where the difference between an array and a lisp-style list of conses comes into play. Somewhat related discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27459561/erlang-sublist-function-performance/27459972#27459972

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the other discussion. Definitely useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no succinct pattern for that.  You can use the functions `lists:last` and `lists:droplast`, which walk the entire list to find the tail:

```
> lists:last([1,2,3]).
3
> lists:droplast([1,2,3]).
[1,2]
```

If you'll be doing this with long lists, you'll probably want to write a function that traverses the list only once but returns both the new list and the last element.  The [source code for `lists:last` and `lists:droplast`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/OTP-17.5/lib/stdlib/src/lists.erl#L206-L229) could serve as inspiration.