# trace can give 'inversion' of processing in folds

Tags: haskell

When I compile the "modified sum" (« _sum_folds.hs ») file :

```
*--------------------------- [

import Debug.Trace 

_sum = 
    foldl ( \ acc x -> 
            trace (
              show x
              ++ " - " ++ show acc
              )
          acc + x
        ) 
        0

*--------------------------- ]

[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( _sum_folds .hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
```

... and apply it to '[1..5]', I get :

```
*Main > _sum ([1..5])

* 1 - 0
* 2 - 1
* 3 - 3
* 4 - 6
* 5 - 10
* 15
* it :: Integer
```

(order for a 'foldl' process is OK ...)

If I remove the < ++ " - " ++ show acc > ,
I get :

( we have only < trace (show x) > )

```
*Main > _sum ([1..5])

* 5
* 4
* 3
* 2
* 1
* 15
* it :: Integer
```

... : the order of processing of the elements inside < [1..5] > (the 'x's) seems have been inverted (it is a 'foldl')...!?

What does it mean ?

Comment: The diagrams in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2169743/2476735) might help.

Answer (score 5):

The expression `foldl (+) 0 [1..3]` creates the following expression tree:

```
              +
             / \
            +   3
           / \
          +   2
         / \
        0   1
```

In your case both `_sum` and `_sum2` build a tree like this:

```
              tr
             / \
            tr  3
           / \
          tr   2
         / \
        0   1
```

Here `tr` is the function in the fold which does the accumulation
and tracing.

## _sum2

The first operation to be visited is the `tr ___ 3` at top of the tree.
The 3 is `x` and ___ is `acc` in the `tr` function.

When this happens in `_sum2` the 3 is printed.

Then `acc` is evaluated, so `tr ___ 2` is evaluated which results in 2 getting displayed.

Then `tr ___ 1` is evaluated, so 1 is printed.

## _sum

However, in `_sum` a difference course of events unfolds (no pun intended).

We again start at the top of the tree: `tr ___ 3`.

**Step 1)**
Since in `_sum` you are also printing out `acc`, Haskell needs to
evaluate it, i.e. `tr ___ 2`.
When this evaluation is complete it will print out `acc` and then 3.

**Step 2)**
To evaluate `tr ___ 2`, since you are printing out the `acc`, Haskell needs to evaluate it, i.e. the tree to the left of the 2 - namely `tr ___ 1`.
When this evaluation is complete it will print out `acc` and then 2.

**Step 3)**
To evaluate `tr ___ 1`, since you are printing out the `acc`, Haskell needs to evaluate the tree to the left of the 1, i.e. 0.
When this evaluation is complete it will print out `acc` and then 1.
In this case 0 is already evaluated, so it prints out 0 and then 1.

Control then transfers back to step 2 and `acc` is displayed (1) and then 2.

Control then transfers back to step 1 and `acc` is displayed (3) and the 3.